# tkinter validation causes duplicate field behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pydev, anaconda

I am trying to write some validated Entry classes in tkinter.  I am on Python 3.3, Anacondas.

In the following code, when I start typing text into one of the two entries, python inserts that text into the other field as I type.  I do not want that.  One field should be a validated date, and the other a validated integer.

What am I doing wrong?

If I comment out all the e1 lines, then it works.  If I comment out the e2 lines then it works. But if I have both together then they are somehow linked.

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *


class ValidatedEntry(Entry):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        Entry.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        if 'default_value' in kwargs.keys():
            self.default_value = kwargs['default_value']
        else:
            self.default_value = 0

        self.previous_value = self.default_value            
        self.config(textvariable=self.default_value)

        self.register(self.__validate_entry())        
        self.config(validate='focusout',validatecommand=self.__validate_entry)

    def __validate_entry(self):

        print('validating')
        try:

            self.validation_function(self.get())
            self.previous_value = self.get()
            return True
        except Exception:            
            self.delete(0,END)
            self.insert(0,self.previous_value)
            return False

    def validation_function(self,value):
        print('should we get here?')
        i=int(self.get())
        #raise NotImplemented('This is abstract so you can''t implement it.')        

class IntegerEntry(ValidatedEntry):           

    def validation_function(self,value):
        print('checking int {0}'.format(value))
        i=int(self.get())

class DateEntry(ValidatedEntry):

    def validation_function(self,value):
        print('checking date {0}'.format(value))
        d=pd.datetime.strptime(value,'%Y-%m-%d')


master = Tk()

e1 = IntegerEntry(master)
e1.pack()
e1.focus_set()

e2 = DateEntry(master)
e2.pack()

b = Button(master, text="get", width=10)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a normal python variable as the value of the `textvariable` attribute. You need to use an instance of `StringVar`, `IntVar`, `BooleanVar` or `DoubleVar`. By using a normal python variable, you're effectively giving both widgets the same `textvariable`, which is why you set one, the other gets set too.

However, since you aren't actually using the `textvariable` attribute for anything, you can simply remove the option altogether and your code will work.

This line also looks suspect:

```
self.register(self.__validate_entry())
```

It's probably not doing what you think it is doing. For one, it's calling your validate_entry function at startup which probably doesn't do anything useful since the user hasn't entered any data yet -- you're just validating the default value. Second, the only reason to call `register` is to use the value it returns, and you're completely ignoring what it returns. You should simply remove that line, it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

This code provides a working solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


class ValidatedEntry(Entry):

    def __init__(self,master,default_value):
        Entry.__init__(self,master)

        if not self.validate_value(default_value):
            raise ValueError('default_value of wrong type')

        self.previous_value = default_value           
        self.insert(0,default_value)        

        self.config(validate='focusout',validatecommand=self.__validate_entry)

    def __validate_entry(self):

        if self.validate_value(self.get()):
            self.previous_value = self.get()
            return True
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo('Validation Error', 'validation failed - reverting to previous value of {0}'.format(self.previous_value))
            self.delete(0,END)
            self.insert(0,self.previous_value)
            return False

    def validate_value(self,value):
        raise NotImplemented('This is abstract so you can''t implement it.')        

class FloatEntry(ValidatedEntry):

    def validate_value(self,value):
        print('checking float {0}'.format(value))
        try:
            f=float(value)
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False    

class IntegerEntry(ValidatedEntry):

    def validate_value(self,value):
        print('checking int {0}'.format(value))
        try:
            i=int(value)
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False             

class DateEntry(ValidatedEntry):

    def validate_value(self,value):
        print('checking date {0}'.format(value))
        try:
            d=pd.datetime.strptime(value,'%Y-%m-%d')
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False



master = Tk()

e1 = IntegerEntry(master,'0')
e1.pack()
e1.focus_set()

e2 = DateEntry(master,'2013-01-01')
e2.pack()

e3 = FloatEntry(master,'10.0')
e3.pack()

b = Button(master, text="get", width=10)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you described what you did to fix it, rather than require that the reader look at every line and try to figure out what you did different.